# Member Function in Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, boolean

Working on a small assignment for class, having a lot of trouble with Haskell. I am trying to make a recursive method for finding if an integer is part of a list or not. I know the gist, but am unable to get it working correctly with the haskell syntax. Check if the current list is empty, if so then False, then check if integer is equal to the head of the current list, if so, then True, then call member again with the same value you are searching for, and the tail of the list. What can I do to get this functioning properly.

Currently this is what I have:

```
member ::Int -> [Int] -> Bool
member x y
if y [] then False
else if x == head y then True
else member x tail y
```

I have also tried using

```
member :: (Eq x) => x -> [x] -> Bool
```

as the beginning line, and also a much simplier :

```
let member x y =  if null y then False
else if x == head y then True
else member x tail y
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you added $ before tail your original version would work. Application is left-associative.

Comment: I added that and I am now getting this error.       Parse error: naked expression at top level
    Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell

Comment: Haven't you forgot about proper indentation?

Comment: I wasn't aware that Haskell required proper indentation. Is it more like Python in that regard?

Comment: You're allowed to use `{}` to help squash some things into one line (unlike Python), but for the most part proper indentation is required. The rule is that things that are underneath some structure need to be indented more than the surroundings.

Comment: note that `member = elem :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool`

Answer (score 3):

with pattern matching you can write it more clearly

```
member :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
member x [] = False
member x (y:ys) | x==y = True
                | otherwise = member x ys
```

Comment: When I use this I get the error:                                                                       • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO t2’ with actual type ‘Bool’                     
    • In the expression: main
      When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’

Comment: That's because you wrote your `main` incorrectly. This implementation of `element` is fine.

Comment: What should the main function look like for this? I currently just have main = do member 1 [1 2 3]

Comment: If you know what a monad is: `main` needs to be an `IO ()`; it can't just be a `Bool` (and `do`-notation will start throwing a fit if you mix `IO` values and pure ones). If you don't: `main = print $ member 1 [1,2,3]`

Comment: I added this and it did fix the problems, but I am looking at it and do not completely understand it. Where it says `member x (y:ys)` what exactly is meant by the `y:ys` piece. I have seen this when searching this problem before, but just do not understand completely what it means. Is that some way to call the tail function on the list of y? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Elmangos This is using pattern matching. Argument 2 is a list, and on the first function definition we match it with the empty list. If it's not an empty list, then it's an item (`y`), and another list (`ys`). `ys` is the tail of the list. If the inputted list was `[1,2,3,4]`, then `y == 1` and `ys == [2,3,4]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
element _ [] = False
element e (x:xs) = e == x || e `element` xs
-- OR
element e xs = if xs == [] then False
               else if e == head xs then True
                    else e `element` tail xs
-- OR
element e xs = xs /= [] && (e == head xs || e `element` tail xs)
-- x `op` y = op x y

-- If you're feeling cheeky
element = elem
```

Your syntax appears very confused, but your logic makes sense, so here's a bucket list of things to remember:

- Functions can be defined by multiple equations. Equations are checked top to bottom. That means using `=`.
- Pattern matches *are not* equality tests. A pattern match breaks a value into its constituents if it matches and fails otherwise. An equality test `x == y` returns a `Bool` about the equality of `x` and `y`.
- Pattern matching is used for flow control via...

  - a `case` statement, like

    ```
    case xs of {
         [] ->    ...
         x:xs' -> ...
    }
    ```
  - Multiple equations, like

    ```
    element _ []     = ...
    element e (x:xs) = ...
    ```

    Note that you can ignore a value in a pattern with `_`. With multiple equations of a function with multiple arguments, you're really pattern matching on all the arguments at once.
- `Bool`s are used for flow control via `if _ then _ else _`:

  ```
  if xs == [] then False
              else True
  ```

  which is really just

  ```
  case x == y of {
       True  -> False
       False -> True
  }
  ```

  and `Bool`s can use the ordinary operators `(&&)` (`infixr 3`) and `(||)` (`infixr 2`)
- The difference is especially nefarious on lists. `instance Eq a => Eq [a]`, so in order to use `==` on lists, you need to know that the elements of the lists can be compared for equality, too. This is true even when you're just checking `(== [])`. `[] == []` actually causes an error, because the compiler cannot tell what type the elements are. Here it doesn't matter, but if you say, e.g. `nonEmpty xs = xs /= []`, you'll get `nonEmpty :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool` instead of `nonEmpty :: [a] -> Bool`, so `nonEmpty [not]` gives a type error when it should be `True`.
- Function application has the highest precedence, and is left-associative:

  - `element x xs` reads as `((element x) xs)`
  - `element x tail xs` reads as `(((element x) tail) xs)`, which doesn't make sense here
- `f $ x = f x`, but it's `infixr 0`, which means it basically reverses the rules and acts like a big set of parentheses around its right argument

  - `element x $ tail xs` reads as `((element x) (tail xs))`, which works
- Infix functions always have lower precedence than prefix application:

  - `` x `element` tail xs `` means `((element x) (tail xs))`, too
- `let decls in expr` is an *expression*. `decls` is only in scope inside `expr`, and the entire thing evaluates to whatever `expr` evaluates to. It makes no sense on the top level.
- Haskell uses indentation to structure code, like Python. [Reference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation)